# Why does * indirection operator gives address in a 2-dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int s[5][3] = { {1,2,6}, {7,3,4}, {8,5,6}, {2555,7,8}, {766,9,0} };
    
    printf("%u %u %u %u %u\n", (s+0), *(s+1), *(s+2), *(s+3), *(s+4));

    return 0;
}
```

C Language code.

In printf statement when I use (s+0) it prints address in the above code. So if I use * operator
i.e. *(s+1) it should give me value at address (s+1). But it's still giving me an address.

**So my question is:**

1. Why isn't * giving value at address?
2. Is (s+0) same as *(s+0)?

**ps.** for 1D array int s[] = {1,2,3}; s is giving value of zeroth element and *(s+i) is giving value of element i of array s.

Comment: `s[0][0]` starts at address 0xffff089 (whatever). `s+0` gives you the pointer at the first element of the array. `*(s+0)` gives you the pointer to the first element of the [][] array which is still a pointer to the value `1`

Comment: All of these expressions are adresses. `s` is two dimensional array, so even the dereference will give you an address.

Comment: Tipp: Enable compiler warnings. With gcc add `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` to see them all. You could figure out more with this allone

Comment: `*(s+4)` is the same as `s[4]` and `*(*(s+4)+3)` is the same as `s[4][3]`.

Comment: Printing an address using `%u` format specifier causes undefined behaviour. Use `%p` and cast the value to `void*`.

Answer (score 0):

Expressions like this `s + i` for the array declaration

```
int s[5][3] = { {1,2,6}, {7,3,4}, {8,5,6}, {2555,7,8}, {766,9,0} };
```

gives the pointer to the i-th element of the array. The element has the type `int[3]`. So the expression `s + i` has the type `int ( * )[3]`.

Dereferencing the pointer you will get the lvalue of the i-th element that is you will get an object of the type `int[3]` i.e an array.

Again an array designator used in expressions with rare exceptions is converted to pointer to its first element.  That is the object of the type `int[3]` is converted to the type int * that points to the first element of the array.

Thus using for example the expression

```
*(s+1)
```

you will get a pointer to the first element of the second "row" of the original array.

Bear in main that the expression  `*(s+1)` is equivalent to the expression `s[1]` that has the array type `int[3]`.

If you want to output first elements of each "row" of the two-dimensional array you need to apply the indirection operator. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int s[5][3] = { {1,2,6}, {7,3,4}, {8,5,6}, {2555,7,8}, {766,9,0} }; 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s ); i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", **( s + i ) );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
1 7 8 2555 766
```

To output the whole array using the pointer arithmetic you could write foor example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int s[5][3] = { {1,2,6}, {7,3,4}, {8,5,6}, {2555,7,8}, {766,9,0} }; 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s ); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeof( *( s + i ) ) / sizeof( **( s + i ) ); j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", *( *( s + i ) + j ) );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 6
7 3 4
8 5 6
2555 7 8
766 9 0
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `s` is not a pointer, it is an array. Applying pointer arithmetic to it will force it to decay to a pointer. In the case of 2D array, the decayed `s` has a type of `int(*)[3]` - a pointer to an array of three integers. Only the outer array will decay.

```c
s+0 == s
/* decayed*/ s == &s[0] // Array decays to a pointer to its first element
&s[0][0] == &s[0] == s // From the previous two (address operator does not stack)
s+1 == &s[1] //Pointer to {7,3,4}
*(s+1) == s[1] // Array {7,3,4}
*(s+1)+0 == s[1]+0 = &s[1][0] // Array {7,3,4} decays to a pointer to its first element
*(*(s+1)+0) == **(s+1) == 7 // First element of array s[1]
```

As an exercise, try to determine the types of the expressions on both sides.

To answer you questions:

1. It is giving a value of `s[0]` which itself is an array which decays to a pointer, hence you get an address. Which is also the same as the address of `s` itself since `s== (s[0]+0)`.
2. No.

```c
>>printf("%u %u %u %u %u\n", **(s+0), **(s+1), **(s+2), **(s+3), **(s+4));
1 7 8 2555 766
```

Comment: `&s[0][0] == &s[0] == s` is false. C is not python. Same problem at `*(*(s+1)+0) == **(s+1) == 7`

Comment: `s[1]+0 = &s[1][0]` does not work because `s[1]+0` is not an lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Three simple steps:

- `s` is an array of 5 arrays of 3 `int`.
- `*(s+1)` is element 1 of `s`. Since `s` is an array of arrays, an element of it is an array; it is an array of 3 `int`.
- When an array is used in an expression, it is converted to the address of its first element.<sup>1</sup>

Thus printing `*(s+1)` or `s[1]` prints the address of the first element of `s[1]`, which is `&s[1][0]`.

However, `%u` is not the correct specification to use for printing an address or an `int`. To print an address, use `%p` while converting the address to `void *`:

```
printf("%p\n", s[1]);
```

To print an `int`, use `%d`, not `%u`. `%u` is for `unsigned int`.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Except an array is not converted to an address when it is the operand of `sizeof`, is the operand of unary `&`, or is a string literal used to initialize an array.

Answer (score 0):

When you access your array `s` it decays into pointer to array to `int` with the length of 3, or `int (*)[3]`. Adding 1 to it means the decayed pointer now points to the next array of 3 elements. When you dereference this pointer you will get a pointer to `int`, adding 1 to this you will increment this pointer to the next `int`

If you have an array of `unsigned char` and a pointer like this (sorry for not using the same array as you did, but it is easier to explain with `unsigned char`.

```
unsigned char s[5][3] = { {1,2,6}, {7,3,4}, {8,5,6}, {255,7,8}, {14,9,0} };
unsigned char *p=*(s+0); //This is equivalent with unsigned char *p=s[0]
```

The data the of this array will be in memory like this (A byte is between every `|`):

```
1|  2|  6|  7|  3|  4|  8|  5|  6|255|  7|  8| 14|  9|  0 
^ p will point to here
```

If you now access `s` and add something to it like so `p=*(s+2);` (which is the same as `p=s[2];`). `s` will be added with the length of 2 array elements, in this case it is `2*3`, because s decayed in an array of length 3. Pointer p will now point to the `unsigned char` at index 0 of the array at index 2 in `s`:

```
1|  2|  6|  7|  3|  4|  8|  5|  6|255|  7|  8| 14|  9|  0 
                        ^ p will now point to here
```

If you add something to it after you dereferenced it, pointer arithmetic will now work on individual `unsigned char` elements. With `p=*(s+2)+1;` (which is the same as `p=&s[2][1];`), `s` will be added with the length of 2 array elements, in this case it is `2*3`, and then added with 1 array element after dereferencing it, in this case 1, which means `p` now points to `5`:

```
1|  2|  6|  7|  3|  4|  8|  5|  6|255|  7|  8| 14|  9|  0 
                            ^ p will now point to here
```